# Does anybody know how to plot a graph in R with RGB values of a core sediment image?

Tags: r, rgb

I have an image of a core sediment and what I want to do is to make a simple plot in R with the RGB values separately, but at the same graph. Is there any advice about that? I attach th image file of the core.[core sediment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvWI9.png)

Comment: Something like this? `library(magick); img <- image_read("path/to/your/image"); image_channel(img, "red")`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using the `png` package:

```r
library(png)

img <- readPNG(readBin("https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvWI9.png", "raw", 1e6))
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))

lapply(1:3, function(i) {
  image(t(img[,,i]), col = grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)), 
        main = c("Red", "Green", "Blue")[i], axes = FALSE)
})
```

[image]

The benefit here is that each of the three channels is held as a matrix in the the first three layers of the `img` array, so you can get the matrix of red values by doing:

```r
red <- img[,,1]
```

and doing the same for green (2) and blue (3)

<sup>Created on 2020-11-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>